# How to predict the output data of 3 columns based on input data of 8 columns in python 3?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk

I have a csv with 12 columns(9 columns as input and 3 columns as output). In input columns there are 5 columns that consist numerical data and rest of 4 columns has string data. In output column 1 column consist date value, other two column consist string value. Like this

```
#input columns

col_1=<int value>
col_2=<int value>
col_3=<int value>
col_4=<int value>
col_5=<int value>
col_6=<string value>
col_7=<string value>
col_8=<string value>
col_9=<string value>

#output columns

col_10=<string value>
col_11=<string value>
col_12=<date value>
```

I have to predict the data of 3 output columns based on data of 9 input column.

How can I do this?
I have seen tutorial of NLTK and positive/negative and comment detection, and https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-12f1e60e0a9f .I tried this with two columns where 1 column as input and other is output:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.corpus import state_union
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

stop_words=set(stopwords.words("english"))

def stop_words_filtering(wordlist):
    return [w for w in wordlist if not w in stop_words]

def tagg(wordlist):
    try:
        #print(wordlist)
        tagged_list=[]
        tagged=nltk.pos_tag(wordlist)
        return tagged
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def filter_words_by_parts_of_speach(words):
    wrd=[word for word,pp in words if pp!='CD' and pp!='']
    return wrd

def join_words(words):
    return ' '.join(words)

df=pd.read_csv('Pescription_details.csv')
col = ['Diagnosis', 'Recomendation/Advice']
df = df[col]
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
df.columns = ['Diagnosis', 'Recomendation/Advice']
for colm in col:
    #df = df[pd.notnull(df[colm])]
    df[colm]=df[colm].str.replace('\n',' ')
    df[colm]=df[colm].apply(word_tokenize)
    df[colm]=df[colm].apply(stop_words_filtering)
    df[colm]=df[colm].apply(tagg)
    df[colm]=df[colm].apply(filter_words_by_parts_of_speach)
    df[colm]=df[colm].apply(join_words)

#df['Diagnosis_id']=df['Diagnosis'].factorize()[0]
#print(df)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['Recomendation/Advice'], df['Diagnosis'], random_state = 0)
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)

print(clf.predict(count_vect.transform(["Hypertension Anxiety Occasional Chest Pain"])))
```

But the prediction result is empty.
Expected output from above code:

```
input:
     Hypertension
     Anxiety
     Occasional Chest Pain
Output:
      Coronary angiograpy.
      Follow up After 3 weeks
```

How can I solve this problem. How can I create Custom classifier? What should I read?

Comment: You should either use Countvectorizer or Tfidf vectorizer, not the output of countvectorizer to the input of Tfidf vectorizer.

Comment: didn't make any difference :(

Comment: could be your data is very small (just 9 records) and all the words in the test data are not present in the input data. you can collect more data or use techniques to generate more data from the current data.

Comment: I have total 87 data. "all the words in the test data are not present in the input data" - yup that is possible